# Bootstrap go from 3 columns to 2 whilst preserving rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout for desktop of 3 columns and 2 rows like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    1. Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    2. dolor sit<br>amet
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    3. consectetur
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    4. adipisicing<br>incididunt
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    5. elit
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    6. sed reprehenderit
  </div>
</div>
```

On mobile I want to achieve a layout of 2 columns and 3 rows that would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    1. Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    2. dolor sit<br>amet
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    3. consectetur
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    4. adipisicing<br>incididunt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    5. elit
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    6. sed reprehenderit
  </div>
</div>
```

So my current solution is to only have a single wrapping `row` and allow Bootstrap to do it's natural wrapping like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    1. Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    2. dolor sit<br>amet
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    3. consectetur
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    4. adipisicing<br>incididunt
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    5. elit
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    6. sed reprehenderit
  </div>
</div>
```

Works fine except when the columns aren't all the same height (which they aren't). In these situation the layout breaks where the floats get caught against an element.

Here's a Plunker example of the problem: https://embed.plnkr.co/eUJCUiGl5VrnTc5Z1c72/

What is the solution in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, and you've got the right idea using a single wrapping `<div class="row">` element. All you need are `clearfix` elements, visible at certain breakpoint values `(xs, sm, md, lg)`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="body">
            1. Multi<br>line<br>content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="body">
            2. Single line
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="body">
            3. Double<br>line
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="body">
            4. More content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="body">
            5. Body
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="body">
            6. Text<br>with<br>many<br>many<br>lines
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

What this does is forces a new row at given intervals - `xs/sm` every other `<div>` and `md/lg` every third `<div>` (which can easily be inserted programatically using a loop). By specifying the `visible-*-block` class, it will only render the `<div>` at certain breakpoints, meaning you won't get accidental spaces.

You can find more documentation [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) and a live example [Here](http://www.bootply.com/tu1sgMJ9Z2)

Example of a Loop to generate this (PHP, but can be done with any language):

```
for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++){
  echo '<div>'.$i.' Words... Blah... Whatever.</div>';
  if($i % 6 == 0){
    echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
  } else if($i % 3 == 0){
    echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>';
  } else if($i % 2 == 0){
    echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block">
  }
}
```

So what this will do is every 2nd iteration print a `clearfix` for `xs/sm`, every 3rd iteration print a  `clearfix` for `md/lg` and every 6th iteration print a `clearix` for both.

Comment: Cool. Yeh this will work fine. I was hoping to avoid adding more html since my grid will actually be system generated with a loop, so adding the clearing divs in your example will be tricky for the back-end devs! Was hoping someone would have an alternative solution. If not, I will accept this answer.

Comment: That's actually pretty simple for a backend dev to solve; it's just like the `fizzbuzz` challenge. I'll add an edit to give you an example.